# Can I resolve PowerShell scriptblock parameters without invoking?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm looking at writing some PowerShell code that can either execute immediately, or produce the commands it would execute as generated scripts.

I'd like to avoid this scenario:

```
if($Generating){
  write-Output "somecommand.exe"
} 
else{
  somecommand.exe  
}
```

I got looking at ScriptBlocks, which at first looked promising because I can write the contents of the ScriptBlock to the console without executing it. Such as:

```
$sc = { somecommand.exe }
$sc
 somecommand.exe
```

My specific question is, if my scriptblock contains parameters, can I get them to resolve when I'm writing the scriptblock contents to the console, but WITHOUT invoking the scriptblock?

For example given the following scriptblock:

```
$b2 = { Param([string]$P) Write-Host "$P" }
```

When I just type "$b2" at the console and hit enter I see this:

```
Param([string]$P) Write-Host "$P"
```

What I'd like to see is this (if the parameter value is "Foo"):

```
Param([string]$P) Write-Host "Foo"
```

I realize this can be done when it's invoked, either via "&" or using Invoke(), but would there be any way to get the parameters to resolve without invoking to make my script generation a little more elegant without needing a bunch of conditional statements throughout the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some of the suggestions I think I've found the best solution for my needs. Consider the following code

```
function TestFunc
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Folder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Foo
    )    

    $code = @"
Write-Host "This is a folder $Folder"
Write-Host "This is the value of Foo $Foo"
"@

    $block = [Scriptblock]::Create($code)

    Write-Host "Running the block"  -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
    &$block

    Write-Host "Displaying block code" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
    $block

}
```

And it's output:

```
Running the block
This is a folder c:\some\folder
This is the value of Foo FOOFOO
Displaying block code
Write-Host "This is a folder c:\some\folder"
Write-Host "This is the value of Foo FOOFOO"
```

By doing it this way, I still get all the benefit of keeping my existing functions and their parameters, parameter validation, CBH etc. I can also easily generate the code that the function would execute or just let it execute. Thanks for all the input, it's definitely been a good learning experience.

Comment: It was an interesting question, too. Just in case, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell v3, you can get the param info via the AST property e.g.:

```
PS> $sb = {param($a,$b) "a is $a b is $b"}
PS> $sb.Ast.ParamBlock

Attributes           Parameters          Extent              Parent
----------           ----------          ------              ------
{}                   {$a, $b}            param($a,$b)        {param($a,$b) "a...
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution suitable for PowerShell v2:

```
# given the script block
$b2 = { Param([string]$P) Write-Host "$P" }

# make a function of it and "install" in the current scope
Invoke-Expression "function tmp {$b2}"

# get the function and its parameters
(Get-Command tmp).Parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

When displaying a here-string with double quotes @**"** , it expands the variables. For the variables that should'nt expand, escape the variable with a backtick ( ` ).

So try this:

```
$P = "Foo"

$b2 = @"
{ Param([string]`$P) Write-Host "$P" }
"@
```

Test:

```
PS-ADMIN > $b2
{ Param([string]$P) Write-Host "Foo" }
```

If you want to convert it to scriptblock-type again:

```
#Convert it into scriptblock
$b3 = [Scriptblock]::Create($b2)

PS-ADMIN > $b3
{ Param([string]$P) Write-Host "Foo" }

PS-ADMIN > $b3.GetType().name
ScriptBlock
```

Comment: The problem is that $b2 is of type [string] and not [scriptblock], it seem cast doesn't works. `$c = [scriptblock]::create($b2)` and use `$c`

Comment: He just said he wanted the output, not that it should be scriptblock, if so he can use `$b3 = [Scriptblock]::Create($b2)`. including it in answer now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express your block as a block, not a string, the following works:

```
$printable = invoke-expression ('"' + ($block -replace '"', '`"') + '"')
```

Essentially, you're wrapping everything in quotes and then invoking it as an expression. The `-replace` call ensures any quotes in the block itself are escaped.

I'm using this in this handy function, which also halts execution if the invoked command failed.

```
# usage: exec { dir $myDir }
function exec($block)
{
    # expand variables in block so it's easier to see what we're doing
    $printable = invoke-expression ('"' + ($block -replace '"', '`"').Trim() + '"')
    write-host "# $printable" -foregroundcolor gray

    & $block
    if ($lastExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        throw "Command failed: $printable in $(pwd) returned $lastExitCode"
    }
}
```